# Scala: methods in trait can't use methods from companion object

Tags: scala, companion-object

When I try to compile the following I get:
"not found: value cons" and "not found: value empty" for the take and drop method definitions.

Somehow the trait doesn't "see" the companion object?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, in case that matters.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

object Run extends App {
  sealed trait StreamRed[+A] {
    def headOption: Option[A] = this match {
      case Empty => None
      case Cons(h,t) => Some(h())
    }

    def toList: List[A] = {
      @tailrec
      def toListRec(stream: StreamRed[A], accumulated: List[A]): List[A] = this match {
        case Cons(h,t) => toListRec(t(), h()::accumulated)
        case _ => accumulated
      }
      toListRec(this, List()).reverse
    }

    def take(n: Int): StreamRed[A] = this match {
      case Cons(h, t) if n > 1 => cons(h(), t().take(n - 1))
      case Cons(h, _) if n == 1 => cons(h(), empty)
      case _ => empty
    }

    @tailrec
    def drop(n: Int): StreamRed[A] = this match {
      case Cons(_,t) if n > 0 => t().drop(n-1)
      case _ => empty
    }

  }
  case object Empty extends StreamRed[Nothing]
  case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => StreamRed[A]) extends StreamRed[A]

  object StreamRed {
    def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => StreamRed[A]): StreamRed[A] = {
      lazy val head = hd
      lazy val tail = tl
      Cons(() => head, () => tail)
    }

    def empty[A]: StreamRed[A] = Empty

    def apply[A](as: A*): StreamRed[A] =
      if (as.isEmpty) empty else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
  }
}
```

Comment: Putting `import StreamRed._` at the top of your trait fixes this.

Comment: thank you, I'm new to Scala. I thought it would work 'automatically' because it's a companion object or is that just for classes+companion object, not trait? I also tried putting the import at the top of the whole thing but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Companions can see each other's members in the sense that access modifiers are not a problem.

```
class A {
  private def foo: Unit = ()

  A.bar 
}
object A {
  private def bar: Unit = ()

  (new A).foo
}
```

is ok on contrary to

```
class A {
  private def foo: Unit = ()

  B.bar 
}
object B {
  private def bar: Unit = ()

  (new A).foo
}
```

(But if you replace `private` with `private[this]` the former won't work either.)

But this doesn't mean that namespaces are imported automatically.

```
class A {
  private def foo: Unit = ()

  import A._
  bar
}
object A {
  private def bar: Unit = ()

  val a = new A
  import a._
  foo
}
```

is ok on contrary to

```
class A {
  private def foo: Unit = ()

  bar
}
object A {
  private def bar: Unit = ()

  foo
}
```

Anyway a method has to know its `this`.